# GPUs can't be used when switching display from first GPU to IGD

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, bios, gpu

I have configured a computer with two gpus, running Windows 7 64. Both cards are detected correctly (they are listed in Windows device manager and in GPU-Z) when my display is connected to my first GPU and when my bios is set to PEG. I can use software that use both gpus, without problems. GPU-Z shows the bios version for both cards, and compute capabilities are all checked.

If I switch the bios setting to IGD and connect my display to the motherboard, weird things happen once in Windows.

1. In Windows device manager, the integrated graphic device is listed,
   as well as my two GPUs (which seems to indicate that the GPUs are
   activated).
2. In GPU-Z, the integrated graphic device is listed as well, so are
   the two GPUs. However, when selecting the GPUs in GPU-Z, they show
   no bios version and all compute capabilities are unchecked (which
   seems to be a problem for the next item).
3. Software are not working anymore, telling that I have no Cuda
   capable GPUs.

I tried connecting a monitor to the first GPU (dummy plug) while set in IGD and it didn't change anything. Do I have to change something else in BIOS?